# Wicket IRequestCycleListener getting feedback messages

Tags: java, wicket

Is it possible to implement a listener using IRequestCycleListener who will be added in application init() method or anywhere else,  and its job would be fetching feedback messages from the appication(for specific page and its componenets). I really don't know where and how I can get this information, in which method to write code (maybe onRequestHandlerResolved)? Or this is not possible at all?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you actually want to do? What do you mean by "feedback messages"? Why do you think this particular class is the way to do it?

Comment: I want to create reusable component to fetch feedback messages on the page where it's added, By feedeback messages I meant messages created with functions: info, warning, error. So I want to fetch all these messages called from any other component on that page and store them in a list(global variable on the page). I was told that this implementation of IRequestCycleListener will help me do this, but I don't know how to use it?

Comment: Isn't FeedbackPanel enough for this?

Comment: It's not enough because I want to use some other component for displaying and processing these messages (KENDO UI control) also  I want to store all messages from more that one request, feedback panel is refreshed on every request. And I am interested in knowing is it possible to do this with some kind of Listener?